# finding part of a long string in a column of short strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table named `Recalls` with a column named `Lotnumber`. The strings in this column are five or six alphanumeric characters.

I have a variable, I'll call `QR`, which is a string of about thirty alphanumeric characters. A lotnumber is buried somewhere inside this string. It can be found in varying positions in the string, which prevents me from using the `MID()` function to find it. 
I need to search through the all the records in the `Recalls.lotnumber` column and alert if any record matches any part of the  `QR` string.

An example of the QR string is: 010035388500971310435252117190731 and the lotnumber is 4352521. I haven't had any luck using the LIKE operator either.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use `LIKE` for this.

```
SELECT lotnumber, CHARINDEX(lotnumber, @QR)
FROM Recalls
WHERE @QR LIKE '%' + lotnumber + '%'
```

But `CHARINDEX` may be a bit simpler

```
SELECT lotnumber
FROM Recalls
WHERE CHARINDEX(lotnumber, @QR) > 0
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Even when I made "@QR" = the exact string as it appears in the Recalls table. >> DECLARE @QR NVARCHAR(50) ='4352521'; SELECT lotnumber
FROM Recalls
WHERE CHARINDEX(lotnumber, @QR) > 0 <<  What did I do wrong?